# Saving money as integer

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

We have the following code in Mongoose schema trying to convert money to integer to save in MongoDB:

```
amount: { type: Number, get: getAmount, set: setAmount, required: true}

function setAmount(num) {
  return num * 100;
}

function getAmount(num) {
  return (num / 100).toFixed(2);
}
```

However saving `64.49` we still end up with this in MongoDB documents:

```
"amount": 6448.999999999999
```

How do we fix this?

Comment: I'm not necessarily sure this may be what the cause of your problem is. Where do you retrieve the numbers and write them to your db? Because `(num / 100).toFixed(2)` should always return a number like `6449.00`

Comment: Use the npm library [mongoose-currency](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-currency)

Comment: 64.99 ends up being 6448.999999999999 in MongoDB after the code above.

Comment: @chridam it's not well supported with too few downloads.  we avoid relying on such packages.

Comment: @krl Check out my answer.

Answer (score 3):

To avoid these kind of precision issue on "money" variables, I always use "cents" as unit.

Don't store 15.24$, store 1524 cents in your code.

Then do all operation using integers.

Then use cents => dollars conversion only for display, by adding "." separator before the last two characters.

Comment: This is exactly what we're doing

Comment: So why do you store "num/100" in your document ?

Comment: Use integer to string, then add "." separator before the last two digits

Comment: Write your own "dollars" to "cents" and "cents" to "dollars" methods, using string manipulation, based on the addition or remove the "." decimal separator (and maybe add one or two 0 if needed). It's simple and keep you integer values everywhere

Comment: I've used that for "online store" applications-like. That was the simplest and best solution to keep the customer a correct amount everytime (even after multiple arimethic operations).

Comment: Clever, but this doesn't help increase the precision (number of significant figures) of your arithmetic operations

Answer (score 0):

Consider using BigNumber: http://mikemcl.github.io/bignumber.js/

Small example (in the console):

```
> 0.2 * 0.4
< 0.08000000000000002
```

And with `BigNumber`:

```
> var a = new BigNumber(0.2);
> var b = new BigNumber(0.4);
> var c = a.times(b);
> c.valueOf();
< "0.08"
```

Comment: Using BigNumber, you don't really solve the "rounding values" problem, only pushing it further

Comment: I see you point, but I do not agree. At the end of the day JS uses the IEEE 754 standard, and we need to be aware of that. What happens if suddenly you'll want to store amounts to the precision of 1/10 of a cent?

Comment: That's a "functionnal" problem I think (I don't know the word in english for that, sorry) : I you need to store with the prevision of 1/10 of a cent, you should not be worried about writing "6448.999999999999" in your document. Because you are using floating points value everywhere, and that's the point of your application.

Comment: You and I as developers understand that. What about paying customers?

Comment: Exactly : a paying customer doesn't understand why "3.17$" + "2.51$" can be equal to "5.679999999999 $".

Answer (score 0):

Does this satisfy your needs?

```
function convert(number) {
    const [i, d] = ('' + number).split(/\./);
    const a = +i * 100;
    const b = +(d || '0').slice(0, 2);
    const c = +(d || '0').slice(2)? 1 : 0;
    return a + b + c;
}
```

Here is the old version that didn't round up the trailing `.0099999`:

```
function convert(number) {
    const [a, b] = ('' + number).split(/\./);
    return +a * 100 + +(b || '0').slice(0, 2);
}
```

It receives 1 number and returns the same number multiplied by 100.